# Save into many to many relationship laravel

Tags: arrays, laravel, save, many-to-many

i have some troubles when i try to save into a manytomany's relationship
basically i don't know how to do that , i only can do it with a simple values from the same table
I have in my database pizzas , ingredients and the pivot table ingredient_pizza.
I want to save some ingredients for one pizza that means an array of ingredients.
I don't have problems when i read ingredients from pizza , but i have problems when i try to save into the database.

Migrations

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('pizzas', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('pizza_name');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}




public function up()
{
    Schema::create('ingredients', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('ingredient_name');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}



public function up()
{
    Schema::create('ingredient_pizza', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');

        $table->integer('pizza_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('pizza_id')->references('id')->on('pizzas');

        $table->integer('ingregient_id')->unsigned();
         $table->foreign('ingregient_id')->references('id')->on('ingregients');

        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Pizza's model

```
public function ingredients()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Ingredient');
}
```

Ingredient's model

```
public function Pizza()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Pizza');
}
```

And i set 2 ingredients for pizza1 by phpmyadmin , and pizza2 doesn't have ingredients

```
//it works , 
$pizza1 = Pizza::find(1);
foreach ($pizza1->ingredients as $ingredient){
    echo $ingredient->ingredient_name;   
}


//it works too ,it shows two ingredients and basically i set the same ingredients for pizza2
$pizza2 = Pizza::find(2);
$pizza2->ingredients=$pizza1->ingredients;
foreach ($pizza2->ingredients as $ingredient){
    echo $ingredient->ingredient_name;   
}
```

but if i want to save the ingredients for pizza2 I have troubles 
i tried save in many ways but it didn't work

```
$pizza2->save;
$pizza2->save();
$pizza2->saveMany;
$pizza2->saveMany();
$pizza2->ingredients->save;
```

if you can give an example , i would like to use new ingredients .
I used the same ingredients because i don't know how can i make new ingredients , save in an array and set into pizza at the same time

Comment: did you make the fields of the table fillable?